# Display a series of characters on each row in descending order SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to display a series of *, starting with 20 on the first row and ending with 1 on the 21th row.

```
DECLARE @number INT
SET @number := 21
SELECT REPLICATE('*', @number := @number-1) FROM information_schema.tables where @number > 0
```

Well, it doesn't work, and I don't know what is wrong. It outputs:

```
Incorrect syntax near ':'.
```

I need a little push in the right direction.

Thanks alot!

Comment: `:=` is not right syntax. What are you trying to do ?

Comment: To display 20 asterisks (*************) on the first row, and then so on until I reach 1 asterisk on the last row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try using the built in `dbo.Numbers` table:

```
SELECT TOP 21
    REPLICATE('*', 22-n) AS output
FROM dbo.Numbers
ORDER BY n;
```

If `dbo.Numbers` is not available in your version of SQL Server, then just use a sequence of some kind.

### Demo

Comment: This block code I understand much better. Thank you so much. As a side note, if you don't immediately understand a block code, means that you just need a lot of practice, not that you are a complete mental retard, right?

Comment: @CatalinCernat Not sure what you're referring to, but _all_ code has a barrier of entry to understand.  Fighting against this barrier is what most of the users who answered your question do for a living.

Comment: built-in? Really?

Answer (score 3):

You mean like this?

```
WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP 20 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1
         CROSS JOIN N N2)
SELECT REPLICATE('*',T.I)
FROM Tally T
ORDER BY T.I DESC;
```

Note this only returns 20 rows though, not 21 (there are 20 numbers between and included 1 and 20)

Comment: The output is what I want. I don't understand the code block. I will never learn SQL. :( Thank you very much!

Comment: @CatalinCernat the first 2 CTE generate what is known as a [Tally Table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/dwainsql/2014/03/27/tally-tables-in-t-sql/). This has advantages over an rCTE, as it isn't recursive. This specific Tally generates 25 rows, of which I use the first 20. I then use `REPLICATE` against the values of the numbers in the tally (1-20) to generate different length values of a `varchar` with the character `'*'`.

Answer (score 2):

You may try with recursive CTE:

```
WITH rcte AS 
(
    SELECT 21 AS [Index]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [Index] - 1
    FROM rcte
    WHERE [Index] > 1
)
SELECT REPLICATE('*', [Index])
FROM rcte
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have an appropriate `ORDER BY` clause, use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ...)` in the opposite direction to generate descending numbers:

```
-- DECLARE @number INT = 21;
-- the variable is not needed, the total number of stars will match total number of rows

WITH your_tbl AS (
    SELECT number
    FROM master..spt_values
    WHERE type = 'p' AND number BETWEEN 1 AND 21
)
SELECT number, REPLICATE('*', ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY number DESC))
FROM your_tbl
ORDER BY number
```